# How do I recursively visit and delete all files in a particular folder which has spaces in sh?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am currently using

```
p=` ls -l -p $MYDIR | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
```

for getting all the folders and then

```
for dirs in ${p}
do
```

for recursively opening the folders. It works fine for folder name without spaces, but for folder names with spaces, the second part of the folder name is selected as a seperate folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all directories under `$MYDIR`,

```
 find "$MYDIR" -type d |
 while read dir; do
    printf '%s\n' "Deleting files in <$dir>"
    rm -f "$dir"/*
 done
```

Note that you must double quote the `dir` variable when using it to prevent the shell from performing *word-splitting* at spaces.

Skipping `$MYDIR` if you don't need it left as an exercise.

Comment: @user3498240 Good! The next step then is to "accept" the answer by clicking the "check mark" to the left under the arrows.

Comment: But one more thing, a find command lists the hidden files too. How do I change the command to not return those? I tried regx parsing but did not work. Is there any simpler method?                                    
Edit: Nevermind, found a way

Answer (score 0):

**You can use:-**

```
find /opt/test  -type d ! -name "test" -exec echo rm -rf \"{}\" \; | sh
```

or

```
find -type d ! -name "." -exec echo rm -rf \"{}\" \; | sh
```

Comment: You will need to Pass Double Quotes for Using Files or Folders with Spaces